# Getting counts of PHP results returned

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

So I've seen this done before, but here's my issue. I'm trying to see if the user posted a post, and if not I'd display a message. The issue is I never seem to get the message. Here's How I'm querying

```
    $posts = array();
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $posts[] =  array(
        'post_content' => $row['post_content'],
        'likes' => $row['post_likes'],
        'time' => $row['post_date'], 
        'id' => $row['id']     
    );
        }
```

And how I'm trying to count

```
<? if(count($posts) < 1): ?>
<h1>No posts</h1>
<? endif; ?>
```

No errors, and I have no records in the DB either.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting no errors? Take a look in your server error log - I bet it's full of them.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
```

will assign `false` to `$row` after the last row has been read. Notwithstanding that this is not an array, the next few lines will assign something to the next element of `$posts`

Thus you'll always get at least one element in `$posts` and you won't see the message. See this [codepad](http://codepad.org/nVCQQZpo)

You should test the `fetch` for false and only process it if it's not.

Change your fetch line to this:

```
while(($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) !== false){
```

Comment: It should be `!==`. It's possible for some functions to return a value that's not `false` but evaluates to `false`. The `!==` form checks for 'identical to'

Comment: @user3100859 If you have a new problem post a new question. If this new issue relates to the existing question and solution then you'll have to provide a lot more detail than a link to PasteBin.